# Adwhirl Integration Problem in Xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, adwhirl

i have integrated Adwhirl in xcode 3.x and Working fine for App
now i am working With Xcode 4.x,Now i am trying to integrate Adwhirl for Xcode 4.x
i am getting problems like in project Building

```
BRBannerAd.h  No Such file or directory
GADAdViewController.h No Such file or directory
GADAdSenseParameters No Such file or directory
```

**i have seen that there is no file like BRBannerAd.h in Adwhirl Sdk,But the Same code wortking in Xcode 3.x Can Any one helpm me to get out of this problem**
Thx in Advance

Comment: If my answer helped you, consider clicking the 'V' sign to it's left.

Comment: some libraries need to be added to the official website maybe this link help:
http://sdk-iphone.adwhirl.googlecode.com/hg-history/c010596032214a8f5696ce0544a75e5c5079d810/iphone/Instructions.txt lib search use google :)

Answer (score 5):

1. Open your XCode project and look through your "adapters" folder of Adwhirl.
2. Remove all adapters related to ad networks your application doesn't use.

in your case, I guess you don't use BRBannerAds and Google-Adsense. so you need to remove their adapters.

it could also be the other way around in which case you would need to add the missing ad networks to your project.